# Print an excel file using Macro. But if the value in one row is 0 then you skip it

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub printF()
    Dim i As Long, printFrom As Long, printTo As Long

    printFrom = Sheet3.Range("AF6").Value
    printTo = Sheet3.Range("AF7").Value

    For i = printFrom To printTo
        If (Sheet3.Range("AE20").Value > 0) 'This check
        Sheet3.Range("AF4").Value = i
        Sheet3.PrintOut Preview:=False
    Next i

End Sub
```

It works fine but if I try to input the checking value if crashes.

Comment: Are you just asking how to construct an `If` block?

Comment: **IF** <condition> **THEN** <statement> **END IF** or **IF** <condition> **THEN** <statement> **ELSE** <statement> **END IF**

Comment: What do you mean with _crashes_? The check will also work in case you have text in AE20 (probably not like expected). It will only crash in case you have an error message in the cell like `#DIV/0!`.
.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just asking how to use an `If` block....

```
For i = printFrom To printTo
    If Sheet3.Range("AE20").Value > 0 Then
      Sheet3.Range("AF4").Value = i
      Sheet3.PrintOut Preview:=False
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You possibly have to add an error check with [IsError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function) before you do a comparision.

```
If Not IsError(Sheet3.Range("AE20")) Then
    If (Sheet3.Range("AE20").Value > 0) Then
        Sheet3.Range("AF4").Value = i
        Sheet3.PrintOut Preview:=False
    End If
End If
```

If you have an error value in the cell the comparision `Sheet3.Range("AE20").Value > 0` will run into a run time error 13